# Why enc28j60 is not responding to another enc28j60?

Tags: avr, embedded, ethernet, tcp-ip, enc28j60

I interfaced enc28j60 with atmega328p. Then I connected the enc28j60 board1 using ethernet cable to my laptop. I have checked the transmission and reception over the ethernet and it worked. I can sent packet and receive packet to/from the laptop. I actually need to communicate with two enc28j60. I have another board which is same as that of first one. I checked the second board for transmission and reception by connecting it to my laptop.

After that I connected frst enc28j60 with second one through a ethernet cable. Both the boards are working individually when i connected it to laptop but not working when connect first board to second board. Already, I verified the ip address and mac address configuration on both boards. But it didn't work.

Whether there is any part that I am missing while doing enc28j60 to enc28j60 communication?

I am using tuxgraphics TCP/IP stack and it working perfectly with my laptop. But the same code is not working to the boards. Both the board have same configuration of all registers only the difference is in the mac address, IP address and port number.

Comment: Have you tried a cross over cable?

Comment: How to check whether I am using straight through cable? Just to confirm. I think I am using straight through cable since both ends have same color wires in position.

Comment: You are probably using a straight through one. You can also try plugging them into a hub or router if you don't have any cross overs.